# Can you ask for additional processors on the fly in MPI?

Tags: c, mpi

With MPI in C, you can do the following to run a program:

`mpirun -np 5 program`

where `5` is the number of processors to use and `program` is the program to run on these processors.  Is it possible to request `x` processors like above but then whilst the program is running, if you decide you need `y` processors (let's say `y>x`), can you request more without restarting the program?

If the answer is yes, then how do you do this?  If no then why not?

Many thanks.

Comment: According to [`lamgrow`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lamgrow) you can just run more.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible; but it's not trivial.  The application needs to have been coded to support this.  Fundamentally, there's the issue that mpi provides various global communication and synchronization primitives, and it's not clear what to do with such operations when adding new parallelism - you wouldn't want new processes to non-deterministically deadlock or crash others, after all.

[Here's some documentation on IBM's site](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/clresctr/vxrx/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cluster.pe521.opuse1.doc%2Fam102_mig_dynamic.html) - any MPI2 implementation should be conform to the same outline.  Jonathan points out that the MPI Specification itself includes [a pretty good example of doing this for a master-worker sort of problem](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi21-report/node205.htm).

Comment: +1, but no, the basics should apply to any MPI implementation that fully implements MPI2.   The MPI Specification itself includes a pretty good example of doing this for a master-worker sort of problem: http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi21-report/node205.htm

Comment: Link added to answer; if you've got any more feel free to add em - CW'd.

Comment: The MPI specifications say how one would do this, but I don't know of any whole system that actually implements it.

Comment: This will all be much more flexible with MPI 4, which has been ratified, but the waiting is for implementations.